# Datagrid paging align right

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, paging

I have a datagrid and I set up the paging based on how many rows there are like this

```
With dgBookings
    .AllowPaging = True
    .PagerStyle.Mode = PagerMode.NumericPages
    .PagerStyle.PageButtonCount = 5
    .PageSize = 5
   End With
```

Is there a way to set the horizontal-align in the code too I tried adding this

```
    .PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = Right
```

and I get this error

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'Length' of 'Public Function Right(str As String, Length As Integer) As String'.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
.PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
```

You need to indicate that it's an enumerator value.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Glad to help. That's what we're all here for.